# $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos(\varphi)}\cos(\varphi-\sin(\varphi))d\varphi$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, trigonometry

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos(\varphi)}\cos(\varphi-\sin(\varphi))d\varphi$$

Maybe with the method of residues. I tried many ways without success. 
Thank a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The integrand is the real part of
$$ e^{\cos{\varphi}} e^{i\varphi-i\sin{\varphi}} = e^{i\varphi} e^{1/e^{i\varphi}}. $$
Putting $z=e^{i\varphi}$, the integral becomes
$$ \Re\int_{\lvert z \rvert = 1} \frac{1}{i}e^{1/z} \, dz, $$
and now you just have to find the real part of the residue at $z=0$ using the power series for $\exp$.

Comment: I'm getting this should be the imaginary part, not the real part, which is zero...(I think)

Comment: Wouldn't the imaginary part be $e^{\cos{\varphi}} \sin{(\varphi-\sin{\varphi})} $?

Comment: Yes... but the residue at $z=0$ is $1$, and then after multiplying by $2\pi i$, the result has $0$ as the real part, when $2\pi$ should be our integral...

Comment: I know what's happened: I forgot the $i$ in the $ie^{i\varphi} d\varphi=dz$.

Comment: :D Ok, just checking that I'm not crazy.